# JSF page is not showing the content

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2

In system user can type a "URL", like "http://www.google.com" and this URL must be processed in SERVER and after the content is showed in XHTML page.

In my XHTML i have:

```
    <h:form id="formNavegador" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <p:inputText value="#{navegadorMB.url}" required="true"
            requiredMessage="A url é obrigatória"
            type="Digite a url para navegar. Ex: http://www.google.com.br" />

        <h:outputText value="#{navegadorMB.htmlContent}" escape="false"
            id="htmlContent" />

        <p:commandButton id="commandButtonProcessar" value="Ir"
            update=":formNavegador:htmlContent" icon="ui-icon-play"
            actionListener="#{navegadorMB.processaRequisicao}" />


    </h:form>
```

So, when user type the URL and click in commandButton, the code bellow is processed:

```
public void processaRequisicao(ActionEvent event){
        if (url.isEmpty()){
            addErrorMessage("Você precisa digitar um endereço");
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().validationFailed();
        }else{
            htmlContent = boPadrao.processaRequisicaoOnServer(url);
            System.out.println(htmlContent);
        }
    }
```

In my method "processaRequisicaoOnServer" the URL is opened and all content is read, after the content of site is returned. See:

```
public String processaRequisicaoOnServer(String url) {
        URL urlObj;
        try {
            urlObj = new URL(url.trim().toLowerCase());
            BufferedReader conteudo = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlObj.openStream()));
            String linha = "";
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
            while((linha = conteudo.readLine()) != null)
            {
                sb.append(linha);

            } 

            return sb.toString();

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new BOException(e.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new BOException(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

So, the content of URL is showed in console because of "System.out.." but the h:outputText is not updated as i hope.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see your entire bean here, but here are some things that I've noticed:

If this is your entire form, you don't need the `enctype="multipart/form-data"`, so you can just remove it.

There is a strange `type` attribute in your first `p:inputText`. Didn't you mean `title`?

```
<p:inputText type="Digite a url para navegar. Ex: http://www.google.com.br" />
```

Also, you don't need to specify the parent of a component when the component is already a child of this parent, so you could change this:

```
<p:commandButton id="commandButtonProcessar" value="Ir" update=":formNavegador:htmlContent" icon="ui-icon-play" actionListener="#{navegadorMB.processaRequisicao}" />
```

to this:

```
<p:commandButton id="commandButtonProcessar" value="Ir" update="htmlContent" icon="ui-icon-play" actionListener="#{navegadorMB.processaRequisicao}" />
```

And you are calling an action listener and passing an `ActionEvent`, which you don't need to, so you could change this:

```
public void processaRequisicao(ActionEvent event) { ...
```

to this:

```
public void processaRequisicao() { ...
```

Furthermore, in order to test it all, you could go in steps, creating a mock method first and checking if things are working properly, and then adding your business stuff.

For instance, to test this you could change your `processaRequisicao` to something like:

```
public void processaRequisicaoMock() { 
    htmlContent = "Funcionou!";
}
```

And then call it, and check if the view is working properly. If it is, you can go on, adding the business layer and all.

I hope it helps.

Comment: The attribute "type" don't do any difference when removed, so i think it's dont matter. I removed but the problem continue

Comment: Is ViewScoped, @icwnd

Comment: Strange, I've reproduced this case here and it works. Are you showing all the code? Are you testing this exact same case or you have a form with more fields than you're showing here?

Comment: I did i test: Putted @SessionScoped and after all process i click F5 To refresh browser, the value show normal in outputText, so we know that value is passed but not updated as i desired.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
 <p:commandButton id="commandButtonProcessar" value="Ir"
        update=":formNavegador:htmlContent" icon="ui-icon-play"
        actionListener="#{navegadorMB.processaRequisicao}" />
```

Try

```
 <p:commandButton id="commandButtonProcessar" value="Ir"
        update="htmlContent" icon="ui-icon-play"
        actionListener="#{navegadorMB.processaRequisicao}" ajax="false"/>
```

Also, change your  method to

```
public void processaRequisicao(){
    if (url.isEmpty()){
        addErrorMessage("Você precisa digitar um endereço");
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().validationFailed();
    }else{
        htmlContent = boPadrao.processaRequisicaoOnServer(url);
        System.out.println(htmlContent);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm updating the "htmlContent" attribute in this line: "htmlContent = boPadrao.processaRequisicaoOnServer(url);"

Comment: Sorry, i did not notice that. I have edited my answer.